# Forbidden node still displays in the menu - how do I prevent this?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've implemented hook_menu_alter to add a custom access function to the standard node/%node menu item in Drupal 6.

```
function amh_workflow_menu_alter(&$items)
{
  $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = '_amh_workflow_access';
}
```

This function works great for determining access when the node itself is displayed to the user - but the menu item for the node is always on display. I would like to have the menu item only display for the user when they have access to the page.

I have tried clearing out the cache a few times, but the menu item stubbornly refuses to hide. This seems really weird, as the other menu items (admittedly, I think they are all using the default user_access and simple access arguments) are all correctly hidden or displayed according to the users' privileges.

I don't understand why the node itself is being protected correctly, but not the menu item. It doesn't seem to me that the access callback is called when displaying the menu (debug messages in the callback method are not displaying).

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to deal with node access.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/group/node_access/6

Comment: For example because it could conflict with other modules that implement node access like Organic groups or Forum access. Also, this only works when a single node is displayed directly but not for listings, views and so on.